# Авторизация используя одну из нескольки баз данных Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте. 
Не могу додуматься как решить проблему с авторизацией в одной из двух баз данных. 
Имеется две одинаковые базы данных, авторизация проходит так: Пользователь выбирает в какой базе он зарегистрировался -> вводит данные -> авторизовывается. 
Когда он авторизовался, появляется проблема, что не известно в какой базе он находится. Вопрос, как записать в какой базе он авторизовался, а именно в $app->user ... создать столбец в базе не подходит, так же как и сессия, ибо сессия быстро исчезает, нежели время жизни авторизации.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

> создать столбец в базе не подходит, так же как и сессия

остались только куки

Comment: Решил использоваться куки, но куки пропадает быстрее чем _identity из-за того появляется ошибка, что не существует данной куки